# How do I install the Unity NavMeshComponents package?

Tags: installation, unity3d

According to the instructions on Unity's GitHub repository for the [NavMeshComponents](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/NavMeshComponents):

> Clone or download this repository and open the project in Unity.

However, Unity does not recognize any of the folders in the download folder as a Unity project. I don't want to just insert things piecemeal into existing projects. Has anyone done this already and can give me help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to use it in an existing Project after downloading the repository from GitHub you need to copy the contents of the `Assets/NavMeshComponents` folder into to the existing project.

> Make a backup of your Project before installing the components.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: I went ahead and put the 'NavMeshComponents' folder inside of the Assets folder of one of my existing projects and it SEEMS to be working. I'm keeping my fingers crossed that it doesn't corrupt anything.